# Error:SELECT command denied to user 'nailuj'@'localhost' for column 'id' in table 'users'bool(false)

Tags: php, mysql

El error inicia aquí `if($result = $cnx->query($sql)){` por qué sucede y cómo podría resolverlo?

````
//conection to server and database
$serverName = "localhost";
$userName = "nailuj";
$passwordServer = "velandia3110";
$dbName = "lession";
//conection for mysqli
$cnx = new mysqli($serverName, $userName, $passwordServer, $dbName);

//check conecction 
if($cnx->connect_error){
    die ("Conection failed: ".$cnx->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email FROM users";


if($result = $cnx->query($sql)){
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        //out data for rows
        while($row =$result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "Id: ".$row['id']." - Name: ".$row['firstName']." ".$row['lastName']." - Email: ".$row['email']."<br>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "0 results";
    }   
}else{
    echo "Error:" . $cnx->error;
}

$cnx->close();
?>```
````

Comment: verifica que tu usuario de MySQL tenga permisos para hacer consultas y también verifica que tu tabla y sus atributos estén bien escritos

Comment: ¿Has probado a conectarte como usuario `root`? Si como `root` te funciona, investiga un poco con `GRANT`

Comment: Gracias, el error era en los privilegios de usuario y ya lo resolví modificando los mismos